# Finding all Combinations of match places with google geolocation Api

Tags: r, geolocation, combinations, google-geolocation

I have one data set like this:

```
 > head(base_1[,c("logradouro","nomemun_x")])
               logradouro      nomemun_x
1      RODOVIA BR-419 KM 236  Anastácio
2      RUA CASTRO ALVES, 1130 São Marcos
3   CONEGO JOAO MARCHESI, 526 São Marcos
4 RUA BONFILHO NICOLETTI, 670 São Marcos
5         VENANCIO AIRES, 444 São Marcos
6         OSVALDO ARANHA, 478 São Marcos
```

and i get a code Find the coordinates latitude/longitude:

```
 geocodeAdddress <- function(address) {
    require(RJSONIO)
    url <- "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="
    url <- URLencode(paste(url, address, "&sensor=false", sep = ""))
    x <- fromJSON(url, simplify = FALSE)
    if (x$status == "OK") {
            latitude <- x$results[[1]]$geometry$location$lat
            longitude <- x$results[[1]]$geometry$location$lng
            localizacao_tipo  <- x$results[[1]]$geometry$location_type
            formatacao_endereco  <- x$results[[1]]$formatted_address
            out<-cbind(longitude,latitude,localizacao_tipo,formatacao_endereco)
    } else {
            out <- NA
    }
    Sys.sleep(0.2)  # API only allows 5 requests per second
    out
}
```

Now a want a program to Make all possible combinations with the variable **logradouro** and **nomemun_x** to find the coordinates that I want.

Comment: use `expand.grid()`

Comment: work with expand.grid() thanks, but now i have combinations like:

Comment: "1130  RUA 1130, São Marcos-RS, 95190000" and i want to exclude the same words or numbers.

Comment: see the update on the post section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df
#                                      logradouro   nomemun_x
#1                   1      RODOVIA BR-419 KM 236   Anastácio
#2                  2      RUA CASTRO ALVES, 1130  São Marcos
#3                  3   CONEGO JOAO MARCHESI, 526  São Marcos
#4                  4 RUA BONFILHO NICOLETTI, 670  São Marcos
#5                  5         VENANCIO AIRES, 444  São Marcos
#6                  6         OSVALDO ARANHA, 478  São Marcos

out <- df[as.matrix(expand.grid(1:nrow(df), 1:nrow(df))),]
head(out, 10)
#                                         logradouro   nomemun_x
#1                      1      RODOVIA BR-419 KM 236   Anastácio
#2                     2      RUA CASTRO ALVES, 1130  São Marcos
#3                     3   CONEGO JOAO MARCHESI, 526  São Marcos
#4                     4 RUA BONFILHO NICOLETTI, 670  São Marcos
#5                     5         VENANCIO AIRES, 444  São Marcos
#6                     6         OSVALDO ARANHA, 478  São Marcos
#1.1                   1       RODOVIA BR-419 KM 236   Anastácio
#2.1                   2      RUA CASTRO ALVES, 1130  São Marcos
#3.1                   3   CONEGO JOAO MARCHESI, 526  São Marcos
#4.1                   4 RUA BONFILHO NICOLETTI, 670  São Marcos
```

or with `cartesian product`:

```
out <- merge(df, df, by=NULL)[1:2]
head(out, 10)
#                                     logradouro.x nomemun_x.x
#1                    1      RODOVIA BR-419 KM 236   Anastácio
#2                   2      RUA CASTRO ALVES, 1130  São Marcos
#3                   3   CONEGO JOAO MARCHESI, 526  São Marcos      
#4                   4 RUA BONFILHO NICOLETTI, 670  São Marcos
#5                   5         VENANCIO AIRES, 444  São Marcos
#6                   6         OSVALDO ARANHA, 478  São Marcos
#7                    1      RODOVIA BR-419 KM 236   Anastácio
#8                   2      RUA CASTRO ALVES, 1130  São Marcos
#9                   3   CONEGO JOAO MARCHESI, 526  São Marcos
#10                  4 RUA BONFILHO NICOLETTI, 670  São Marcos
```

Comment: to get rid of the rows having same values in the columns `logradouro.x, nomemun_x.x` filter with `out <- out[out[,1]!=out[,2],]`